# step function vs integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The Problem:

Let f be an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure. Thern for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a finite collection of intervals $E_1, . . . , E_k$ (that is, $E_i = [a_i, b_i])$ and constants $a_1, . . . , α_k$, such that $ \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left| f(x)-\sum_{i=0}^{k}{\alpha_i 1_{E_i}(x)} \right|} dx <\epsilon$

My problem is the start. How should I begin proving it? How can I say that these intervals and constant exist?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I suggest starting by reducing the problem to compactly supported functions.

Comment: mmh sorry it doesn't help me so much actually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

1. Start by reducing the problem to positive functions (that is, show that if it holds for every positive function, then it also holds for any integrable function).
2. Reduce the problem to positive functions with compact support.
3. Reduce the problem to simple functions, and in particular to an indicator function.

---

**Added** (it should be safe to say a few more words now) for ease of notation, call a simple function $h=\sum \alpha_j1_{E_j}$ where each $E_j$ is an interval an R-simple function.

1. Decompose $f=f_+-f_-$. If $h_+,h_-$ are R-simple such that
   $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f_+-h_+|dx<\frac{\epsilon}{2};\quad \int_\mathbb{R}|f_--h_-|dx<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
   then
   $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f-(h_+-h_-)|dx \leq \int_\mathbb{R}|f_+-h_+|dx + \int_\mathbb{R}|f_--h_-|dx\leq \epsilon.$$
   We can therefore assume w.l.o.g. that $f$ is positive.
2. $f\ 1_{[-n,n]}\to f$ pointwise, and by the monotone convergence theorem we can take $n$ such that $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f-f\ 1_{[-n,n]}|dx\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
   If $h$ is R-simple and $\int_\mathbb{R}|f\ 1_{[-n,n]}-h|dx\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then w.l.o.g. $h$ is also supported in $[-n,n]$, and we have $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f-h|dx\leq\int_\mathbb{R}|f-f\ 1_{[-n,n]}|dx+\int_\mathbb{R}|f\ 1_{[-n,n]}-h|dx\leq\epsilon.$$
   We can therefore assume w.l.o.g. that $f$ is compactly supported.
3. The definition of Lebesgue integral affords us a simple function $g$ dominated by $f$ (hence also compactly supported) such that $\int_\mathbb{R}|f-g|dx<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Again, if $h$ is R-simple and $\int_\mathbb{R}|g-h|dx\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then
   $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f-h|dx\leq \int_\mathbb{R}|f-g|dx + \int_\mathbb{R}|g-h|dx\leq\epsilon.$$
   We can therefore assume w.l.o.g. that $f$ is a compactly supported simple function. Moreover, by a similar process to (1), we can assume w.l.o.g. that $f$ is a compactly supported indicator function.

We're left needing only to prove the proposition for $f=1_A$ for some bounded and measurable $A$. The regularity of the Lebesgue measure admits $K\subset A\subset G$, $K$ compact and $G$ open, such that $\int_{G\setminus K}dx<\epsilon$. By compactness, we have finitely many open intervals $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ such that $K\subset \bigcup E_j\subset G$, and it can now be easily shown that $E^\prime_i = E_i\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals and that $\int_\mathbb{R}|f-\sum 1_{E^\prime_i}|dx\leq\epsilon$.

Comment: That's cool! I still have one question. Did you really mean $f=1_A$ in the last paragraph or $h=1_A$? By 3. we want $E(|f-h|)<\epsilon$ for h simple right? I wrote $E(|f-h|)\leq E(|f-g|)+E(|g-h|)$ but how can I say that the second integral is less than $\epsilon/2$?  Thanks a lot

Comment: @sky90 in the last paragraph I do mean $f$. The purpose of the 3 steps above is to show that solving the problem for (compactly supported) indicator functions (which is to say, the set is bounded) also solves it in the general case.

Comment: @sky90 As for part (3), by (2) we know that it suffices to thusly approximate positive functions with compact support. So our aim is to *assume* it could be done for simple functions with compact support (effectively *assuming* the last integral is bounded that way), and *show* this implies it can also be done with any positive function with compact support (so, by (2), we would be done).

Comment: ok, but why can we assume this? =)

Comment: @sky90, that's the process of reduction: instead of showing $\mathrm{Val}\left(A\to B\right)=\mathrm{True}$, you show that $\mathrm{Val}\left((C\to B)\to(A\to B)\right)=\mathrm{True}$. Only then do you turn to prove that $\mathrm{Val}\left(C\to B\right)=\mathrm{True}$. For the purpose of the middle step, the case $\mathrm{Val}\left(C\to B\right)=\mathrm{False}$ doesn't matter.

Comment: @sky90 if you prefer, read the paragraphs from end to beginning. First you learn that the proposition holds for indicator functions, then you see this implies it holds for simple functions, then you learn it holds for functions with non-compact support, and lastly we show it even holds for non-positive functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot :)